# Why is rendering and viewport shading pixelated?

Tags: rendering

[image: This is obviously a cube but I didn't alter anything about it.]

I just started using Blender and was trying the donut tutorial but the donut kept looking like this so I thought maybe I messed up somewhere.

When I started over I checked to see if it was happening with the cube and it was, I didn't change anything about it. Whenever I enter viewport shading the cube becomes covered in noise.

I don't know how to describe it and I tried taking a screenshot but it wasn't working either.

Comment: Is this what you have in rendered viewport shading, or in solid shading? If in rendered, try playing with the [Pixel Size](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html#viewport) setting. If in solid shading,  then I'd bet it's a graphics driver issue.

Comment: This is just what happened when I hit render image, the viewport shading has the edges covered in like pixels/noise

Comment: `I tried taking a screenshot but it wasn't working either.` is the picture in your post an actual screenshot of your issue?

Comment: Because having noise in your render is normal, that only depends on your render settings. But what you show looks more like a lowered viewport resolution or a display issue. If that's not a screenshot of your viewport, and it's really what you get when rendering (via the menu Render > Render Image or pressing F12), then to me it's a bug. Make sure you meet up [Blender's system requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/), reinstall the latest graphics driver for your GPU, and try again.

Comment: its one of them, I thought maybe the two issues are connected. I'm like brand new to this so I am sorry if I am not answering this well. The model in viewport shading is covered in pixels then when I hit render image it turns out like this

Comment: So I'm leaning towards a hardware/system issue. As explained in my previous comment, check you meet up the requirements, reinstall your driver, and try again. Please keep us posted of any progress.

Comment: well I uninstalled it because I thought maybe I have an outdated version cause I downloaded it a while ago but never used it. I reinstalled it but now when I try to render anything it crashes and closes, the same goes for viewport shading. I'm starting to think maybe my computer can't handle it.

Comment: still the same answer as last time.